# How to construct a table from multiple and independent select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I looked into some related questions but I couldn't find help.

I am trying to sort of create a statics table which shows number of companies completed sign up steps. I have done all the heavy work and I am able to just use a simple select statement to see how many completed, say it, step 1. But I wanted to kinda write a select statement that will contain `step 1 step 2 step 3 (columns) with number (values)` of companies completed each step.

```
step table 

----------------------------------------------------
progress_id | label | level | score | is_completed | 
----------------------------------------------------
```

**progress_id:** Company we are tracking progress

**label:** step level label, e.g: Company email has been verified,

**level:** say step one,

**score:** e.g: 20%,

**is_completed:** true/false

You see with this, I can simply do:

`select count(*) step_one_count from step where level = 1 and is_completed = true`;

```
----------------
step_one_count |
----------------
20
```

`select count(*) step_two_count from step where level = 2 and is_completed = true`;

```
----------------
step_two_count |
----------------
10
```

I then need to write one select statement, be it with subquery or whatever to acheive this result below

```
----------------------------------------------------
step_one_count | step_two_count | step_three_count |
----------------------------------------------------
20               10               40
```

Comment: Tag the only DBMS that you are actually using.

Comment: It seems your step_three_count will be 30

Comment: I'd go with a basic GROUP BY: `select level, count(*) from step where is_completed = true group by level`

Comment: @YogeshSharma: I'm sorry I actually added it but I don't know why it wasn't added

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin: Numbers do not really matter

Comment: @tbuglc number matters because by seeing that number have to take decision what will be the logic for that output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin: I'm afraid to say no. I actually use those numbers to update `progress` table, column: `status: complete | incomplete if total_score = 100` in case a company has 100 as total score. Each step is worth 100/number_of_steps.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin
With this setup, it's much more easy to tell which step a user completed and which s/he didn't as steps are not sequential (Users don't need to complete step two to start three). For some reason, it's a poor design as far as sign up process is concerned but yeah, this is aiming at fixing the existing bug and later on we'll constraint users to complete steps in linear order. Great thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want *conditional* aggregation, in `MySQL` you can do  :

```
SELECT SUM( (level = 1 and is_completed = true) ) AS step_one_count,
       SUM( (level = 2 and is_completed = true) ) AS step_two_count,
       SUM( (level = 3 and is_completed = true) ) AS step_three_count
FROM step s;
```

In standard way you can use `CASE` Expression instead :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN level = 1 and is_completed = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) AS step_one_count,
       . . . 
FROM step s;
```

**EDIT :** As you tagged `DBMS` you can use `FILTER` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE level = 1 and is_completed = true) AS step_one_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE level = 2 and is_completed = true) AS step_two_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE level = 3 and is_completed = true) AS step_three_count,
FROM step s;
```

Comment: I can't tell how much I love stackoverflow for you'all guys. Just works with **EDIT** code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
   select 
   sum(case when level = 1 and is_completed = true then 1 else 0 end) 
   as  step_one_count,
   sum(case when level = 2 and is_completed = true then 1 else 0 end) 
   as step_two_count,
  sum(case when level in (1,2) and is_completed = true then 1 else 0 end)
   as step_three_count        
    from step
```

Comment: ```ERROR:  function sum(boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: select sum(level = 1 and is_completed = true) as step_one_co...```